# cv2_imshow return PIL object instead of display image on Colab

Tags: python, opencv, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I am facing a problem in displaying image on Colab.  The code that I run is in .py file which I run on Colab, so in that file I have import cv2_imshow instead of normal cv2 and called it in a file. `from google.colab.patches import cv2_imshow`

When I run it, it is working with no errors but the function cv2_show is not displaying image instead it return object.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSq4n.png)

It return this instead `<PIL.Image.Image image mode=RGB size=400x400 at 0x7F0B8C132C10`>

```
        # Frame's Shape (400,400,3)
        print(type(frame))
        
       
        cv2_imshow(frame)
```

The input I pass to it is in numpy array of shape (400,400,3)

I tried another way by saving an image and use PILLOW to display it  and it still give object but different type of object `<PIL.JpegImagePlugin.JpegImageFile image mode=RGB size=400x400 at 0x7FF8C204D7D0>`.

```
        # Frame's Shape (400,400,3)
        cv2.imwrite('landmark_test.jpg', frame)
        #cv2_imshow(frame)
        dpi = Image.open('landmark_test.jpg')
        display(dpi)
```

[image]

Comment: I do not understand your question. Please click `edit` and add the simplest possible, **complete** code that  causes a problem, even if it just creates a red rectangle with Numpy and displays it. Thank you. Please also paste error messages rather than pictures of them.

Comment: @MarkSetchell So there is no error but cv2_imshow doesn't display image but instead in return an object. The input is numpy array of size (400,400,3). I even try with Matplotlib it doesnt even print anything out.

Answer (score 0):

Using `!python yourScript.py` might not display images correctly because it runs the script as a separate process, which doesn't integrate well with Colab's output system. Instead, images are shown as `<PIL.Image.Image>` object references, not as visual content.

To ensure images display correctly, replace `!python` with the `%run` magic command. This executes your script in the IPython context, ensuring integration with Colab's output rendering.

Replace:

```py
!python script_name.py
```

With:

```py
%run script_name.py
```